# How to check an IGBT

Tags: igbt

I want to check an IGBT FGA25N120ANTD whether it is broken or not. I have a good multimeter.

I followed some online videos I cannot figure out the right way.
Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 5 tests you can perform

1) impedance check

Collector-Emitter  - should be Megs

Gate-Emitter - should be megs unless internal GE terminator resistor

2) Capacitive check

Gate-Emitter - should be capacitive ... (read further down)

3) Diode check

DMM on diode and Emitter - collector - should be a diode

4) withstand

Megger on 500V (or suitable level for the breakdown voltage BUT less than) Collector-Emitter

5) switch test

20V PSU Collector-Emitter with say... 1A limit, 15V PSU Gate-Emitter - 1st PSU should go into current limit

Do these tests on a known working switch so you know what to expect.

Comment: Not sure this is totally clear.  What's a Meg?  Megger? PSU?  Does that terminator resistor really need to come from General Electric? Possible to decode this into plain english, so an average Joe could say... test an IGBT?  Question.  I see lots of videos online talking about testing an IGBT with 12v battery and lamp.  Which of your tests serves as that function?  (The fact that I can't tell suggests your descriptions could possibly be improved...or is that a sixth suggested test?) . Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: the answer is fine. Those that know what an IGBT is, know what a PSU is, know what a Megger is, know where the GE is.  Please familiarize yourself with an IGBT. Your "average Joe" should not be going near one as these involve 600-1200V

Answer (score -1):

Try a diode check across the collector and emitter. If the IGBT is dead, it should read 0 volts.

Comment: Maybe you could add a little more detail on the test and how it should be performed in some more detail?